# Why the sequence from the bitwise operator(~) would be this? Is that broken?

Tags: c++, printf, bitwise-operators, integer-promotion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
unsigned char a=100,b=50;

printf("%d & %d = %d\n",a,b,a&b);
printf("%d | %d = %d\n",a,b,a|b);
printf("%d ^ %d = %d\n",a,b,a^b);
printf(" ~%d = %d\n",a, ~a);       /*the out come of this  line would be this: ~100 = -101 */
printf(" %d >> 2= %d\n",a, a>>2);
printf(" %d << 2= %d\n",a, a<<2);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

/*the out come should be 155 ,isn't it?*/

Comment: Hint: 256 - 101 = ?

Comment: It's not broken, but your `printf` calls are.  Try `printf(" ~%hhu = %hhu\n", a, ~a);` ...  and please, you've tagged this question as C++ so stop using the C library functions.

Comment: There is no [tag:operator-keyword] here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the standard, the operand of `~` will undergo integral promotion. So here we will first promote `a` to `int`.

> [[expr.unary.op]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#10): The operand of ~ shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type; the result is the ones' complement of its operand. **Integral promotions are performed.**

If `int` is 4 bytes (for example), the value of the promoted `a` is `0x00000064`. The result of `~a` is `0xFFFFFF9B`, which is exactly `-101`(If using two's complement to represent integers).

Please note that although variadic arguments will undergo integral promotion, here `~a` is of type `int` and no additional promotion is required.

Answer (score -2):

```
100 = 0x64
~0x64 = 0x9B
```

In `printf(" ~%d = %d\n",a, ~a);`, the second format specifier `%d` expects a `signed integer`, so the result **0x9B** will be extended to a `signed integer`. The MSB of **0x9B** is 1, so it is regarded as a `negative value`.

```
0x9B ---extends to>>> 0xFFFFFF9B = -101
```

If you want the result as `155`, you need a `unsigned` cast so the `0x9B` will be extended to `0x0000009B`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned char a = 100, b = 50;

  printf(" ~%d = %d\n", a, ~a);
  printf(" ~%d = %d\n", a, (unsigned char)~a);

  return 0;
}
```

This will give result:

```
gcc test.c
./a.out

 ~100 = -101
 ~100 = 155
```

Comment: you should clarify which operation caused the subtle promotion: the negation operator or the call of `printf`?

Comment: Your first paragraph is just utter nonsense. That's not how C or C++ works.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I didn't say they are C/C++ code. It is pseudocode for explanation, and most programmers will understand.

Comment: @ZongruZhan I'm not talking about the code snippet. I'm talking about the text below.